# Hausdorff topology on manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, solution-verification, separation-axioms

I've to prove the following result but I'm not sure about my solution.

Prove that the topology on a manifold $M$ is of Hausdorff iff it admits an atlas $\mathcal{A}=\{U_{\alpha}, \phi_{\alpha}\}$ with the following property: $\forall$ couple of points $p,q\in M$ there exists a chart such that $p,q \in U_{\alpha}$ or two charts such that $p\in U_{\alpha}$ and $q\in U_{\epsilon}$ and $U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\epsilon}=\emptyset$.

Proof
Let we suppose to have a Hausdorff topology on $M$. Then we have that for each couple of distinct points  $p, q \in M$ there exist two open sets, $A$ containing $p$ and $B$ containing $q$, such that $A \cap B =\emptyset$. The topology on $M$ is induced by the charts i.e. $U_{\alpha}\in \mathcal{A}$ is open iff $\phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let we consider two scenario. If $\phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and contains both $\phi_{\alpha}(p)$ and $\phi_{\alpha}(q)$ such that $\phi_{\alpha}(q)\neq \phi_{\alpha}(p)$ we are able two find two other charts $U_{\beta}$ and $U_{\gamma}$ in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\phi_{\alpha}(q) \in \phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta})$
$\phi_{\alpha}(p)\in \phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\gamma})$ and $\phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\gamma})\cap \phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta})= \emptyset$. If would not be the case, $M$ could not has the Hausdorff property, which needs to be true for each chart in the atlas.
Since $\phi_{\alpha}$ are homomorphisms, the same holds for $U_{\gamma}, U_{\alpha}$ and $U_{\beta}$ i.e.
$(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\gamma})\cap (U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta})= \emptyset$.

The same reasoning holds for $\phi_{\alpha}(q)\neq \phi_{\epsilon}(p)$ belonging to different open sets of $\mathcal{A}$, $U_{\alpha}$, $U_{\epsilon}$.

Suppose the by contradiction that $M$ has not the Hausdorff property. This means that we cannot find out at least two open set in the atlas, containing two distinct points, such that their intersection is void.
Since holds  $\phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\gamma})\cap \phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta})= \emptyset$ for $\phi_{\alpha}(q)\neq \phi_{\alpha}(p)$, $\phi_{\alpha}(q)\in \phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta}), \phi_{\alpha}(p) \in \phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\gamma})$  from the previous case and
$\phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\gamma})$ and  $\phi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta})$ are open as theri inverse image (which exists and it's open sine $\phi_{\alpha}$ is an homomorphism), we get an contradiction. The same holds for the second case.

Let me know if the proof is correct.
Thanks.

Comment: The most common definition of a manifold requires that it be metrizable, which implies Hausdorff. Evidently you are not using this common definition, so it would help if you included the definition that you are using.

Comment: @LeeMosher I agree that the OP should include the definition he is using. But I do not agree that the most common definition of a manifold requires that it be metrizable. In my opinion "the usual" definition is that a manifold is a second countable Hausdorff space that is locally homeomorphic to Euclidean space. This implies metrizability. Anyway, the OP's definition cannot include "Hausdorff" or something stronger.

Comment: For sake of clarity, the definition of manifold (Abate, Tovena, Differential Geometry),I assume is the following : "A manifold of dimension n is a set M equipped with a differential structure of dimension n which induces a Hausdorff topology on M with a countable basis". The definition of "differential structure" is : "an atlas of dimension n on M which is maximal with respect to the inclusion relation" (in general, more altas are allowed). Let me know if, by these definitions, my arguments appear more clear (and if  there are some mistakes which need to be corrected). Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Alessandro Then your question does not make sense. A manifold is Hausdorff **by definition**. But you can prove that there exists an atlas on $M$ having the property in your question.

Comment: I posted the text of the exercise as it is. However, are my arguments correct? Are there any errors?

Comment: @Alessandro The point is that your question cannot be about manifolds in the sense of your definition (which includes the Hausdorff property). Thus for a manifold $M$ is does not make sense to show that the existence of a certain atlas implies Hausdorff. I recommend to modify your question by considering a space $M$ which is locally Euclidean without any other properties.